# Reference with supertype lifetime can't be used for subtype lifetime

Tags: rust

I'm struggling to understand how subtyping of lifetimes works. The name `subtype` suggests to me that if `'b` is a subtype of `'a`, then things of type `'a` can be used anywhere something of type `'b` will be used. And practically, in the context of lifetimes, I don't see what could go wrong from allowing that. However, the following code

```
fn test<'a, 'b: 'a>(first: &'a mut str, second: &'b mut str) -> &'b str {
    // do something to choose between the two arguments,
    // eventually pick first on some branch
    first
}
```

doesn't work, because "these two types are declared with different lifetimes... but data from `first` flows into `second` here."

So what would go wrong if this was allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what would go wrong if this was allowed?

Your reasoning was *inverted* in this example: a constraint `'b: 'a` reads as *"`'b` lives as long as `'a`"*. Since the output of `test` needs to live for *at least* as long as the lifetime `'b`, `'a` still represents a possibly incompatible lifetime, and `first` might actually not live long enough.

If you flip the lifetimes around, the code will then compile.

```
fn test<'a, 'b: 'a>(first: &'b mut str, second: &'a mut str) -> &'a str {
    first
}
```